# Can't link Localhost:3000 Ruby on Rails Page with Heroku - One Month Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, sublimetext2

I was not able to install Ruby on Rails from the One Month Rails by Mattan Griffel tutorial because I am using iOS Mavericks (The tutorial is from 2013). I have no idea what I'm doing and I am trying to figure it out as I go. I was finally able to `$ git push heroku master` without error but when I tried to use the link that was given from Heroku, it did not link to my localhost:3000 Ruby on Rails page like it was supposed to.

I have since made changes and now I fear I have only dug the hole deeper.

```
Demo:omrails Demo$ git push heroku master
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 20, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (17/17), done.
Writing objects: 100% (17/17), 1.55 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 17 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.6.3
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
   Using minitest 4.7.5
   Using multi_json 1.10.1
   Using i18n 0.6.11
   Using thread_safe 0.3.4
   Using tzinfo 0.3.41
   Using builder 3.1.4
   Using erubis 2.7.0
   Using rake 10.3.2
   Using mime-types 1.25.1
   Using rack 1.5.2
   Using polyglot 0.3.5
   Using activerecord-deprecated_finders 1.0.3
   Using arel 4.0.2
   Using coffee-script-source 1.7.1
   Using execjs 2.2.1
   Using thor 0.19.1
   Using hike 1.2.3
   Using pg 0.17.1
   Using bundler 1.6.3
   Using json 1.8.1
   Using tilt 1.4.1
   Using activesupport 4.0.0
   Using coffee-script 2.3.0
   Using uglifier 2.5.3
   Using treetop 1.4.15
   Using activemodel 4.0.0
   Using mail 2.5.4
   Using rack-test 0.6.2
   Using sprockets 2.11.0
   Using activerecord 4.0.0
   Using actionpack 4.0.0
   Using actionmailer 4.0.0
   Using sprockets-rails 2.0.1
   Using railties 4.0.0
   Using jquery-rails 3.1.1
   Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
   Using rails 4.0.0
   Your bundle is complete!
   Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
   It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
   Bundle completed (0.74s)
   Cleaning up the bundler cache.
   Removing turbolinks (2.2.2)
   Removing sass (3.2.19)
   Removing rdoc (4.1.1)
   Removing sass-rails (4.0.3)
   Removing jbuilder (1.5.3)
   Removing sdoc (0.4.1)
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   rake aborted!
   Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'turbolinks'
   (in /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-    
b40112014d6b/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:15)
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-   
   b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets- 
2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:106:in `resolve'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-
b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-
2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:146:in `require_asset'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:217:in `process_require_directive'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:167:in `block in process_directives'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:165:in `each'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:165:in `process_directives'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:99:in `evaluate'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:12:in `initialize'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:37:in `init_with'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/asset.rb:24:in `from_hash'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:54:in `cache_asset'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in `benchmark'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in `block in compile'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `compile'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:60:in `block (3 levels) in define'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
   /tmp/build_d6668242-8173-4c2f-b925-b40112014d6b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in define'
   Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
   (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:powerful-fjord-2879.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:powerful-fjord-2879.git'
Demo:omrails Demo$
```

Answer (score 1):

> I was not able to install Ruby on Rails from the One Month Rails by
>   Mattan Griffel tutorial because I am using iOS Mavericks (The tutorial
>   is from 2013)

- Try a newer tutorial.
- You can install Rails on Mavericks by just running `gem install rails`. [Here's an up to date article on doing that](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html).

> I tried to use the link that was given from Heroku, it did not link to
>   my localhost:3000 Ruby on Rails page like it was supposed to

- Heroku is not supposed to link to your localhost.
- When you deploy your code from your computer (localhost) you are sending your code to another computer (some other host) and you will be able to access your app via that other computer's domain name (your-app.herokuapp.com). Had your deploy succeeded, Heroku would have output in its last line in your terminal the domain where you can view your deployed app in e.g. powerful-fjord.herokuapp.com.
- To recap: when you run `rails server` on your computer, Rails will spin up it's builtin web server and allow you to view your web app at `localhost:3000` (this is like a URL you would type in your browser's address bar). When you deploy to Heroku, it itself is a computer running a webserver and you can view it at the domain heroku gives you (or the one you configure for it later on) typically something like `powerful-fjord.herokuapp.com` or whatever you named your app when you ran `heroku create my-app-name-here`.

Finally, the error that is preventing the `git push heroku master` command from succeeding is hinted to by this line in the output:

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'turbolinks'
```

This means your Rails app is missing a javascript file named turbolinks.js. You might need to add turbolinks to your Gemfile: `gem 'turbolinks'` or remove this line from your application.js: `*= require turbolinks`. Do that and your deploy should work.

As far as up to date tutorials, the aforementioned site Railapps is a good source. Here's their tutorial: https://tutorials.railsapps.org/rails-tutorial